# System Error &H80000FFFF (-2147418113) when using macros in Word 2016

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word-2016, microsoft-surface-pro-3

When I try to use any of my macros in Word, I get the following:

```
System Error &H80000FFFF (-2147418113) 
Catastrophic Error
```

I have uninstalled, reinstalled Word 2016, run all the repair options. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Have you tried using that same macro on a different document? Have you tried save-as-ing your current document in a different location and trying again there? Also, this is a macro-enabled document (.docm), right?

Comment: Yes it is a Macro-enabled document, saved in multiple locations, always same result for any of my macros. This is a very sudden problem. Macros worked fine one day, and suddenly this problem. Can't imagine ...

Comment: Can even record a new macro, then same problem when I try to run the new macro. Wow!

Comment: Are you running the macro through the dialog or through the VBA window? Have you tried stepping through the macro in the VBA window to see if it fails at a particular line?

Comment: Can't step through because I can't even begin to run or debug the thing, and same result whether I run through the developer tab, a shortcut I have, or the VBA window.

Comment: Hm. Have you upgraded your version of Office recently? I found [this link](https://damir-vadas.blogspot.com/2011/02/macro-cannot-be-found-or-has-been.html) that traces the problem through Windows Event Viewer and pinpoints it to a version incompatibility between files common to two Word versions.

Comment: Do you possibly have access to another computer that you could open that file from? That should tell you if it's the problem of the file or of your Word. Also, is the record-macro-and-run functionality broken on just that file, or any file saved locally on your drive?

Comment: And you are using UserForms, right? Did you possibly use some code from a previous version of Office? (Though that should really only pollute the current document you have open - if you only have a totally blank document open, that shouldn't affect you.)

Comment: No recent upgrades, but all is current. I will delve into the event viewer. This will be a learning curve, but I'll give it a whirl. Thanks!

Comment: What I'd recommend is opening Event Viewer, try to replicate the problem, and refreshing to see if there are any new errors or warnings (probably under the Application log). Editing your answer and adding what you find might get you some more answers.